# Node Application Crash when sending request

Tags: node.js, angular, passport-local

I have been working on a Node application. When i try to run gulp on application , i am facing this error

```
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of null
    at passport.conf.js:366:30
    at Array.map (native)
    at passport.conf.js:364:37
    at D:\boibazar-admin_\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:3932:16
    at process.nextTick (D:\boibazar-admin_\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:1456:39)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:128:9)
[13:54:26] [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

It was working perfectly before my windows update. After updating windows (21H1) the application crash all the time when i try to login the system.
Node version of my Application is **6.17.1** and i am using **passport-local authentication**.
In fornt-end i am using "angular 4". As a new developer in node.js, can anyone help me to sort it out

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling the packages? (delete node_modules, ``npm install``)

Comment: Tracer69 yes i tried, but it fails everytime.

Comment: You should update the node version first, it is a suggestion as node 6 is too old to use now though you can use it, but such scenarios might occur more frequently.  From the error what i can see is there is an issue with the code as you are reading property of null that should not be of course because of updates.  Can you update the code?

Comment: can you kindly add passport.conf.js

Comment: @LawrenceCherone here it is **[passport.config.js](https://pastebin.com/Ls0cP30h)**